# Magento 2: Different stores with different customers, products and admin accounts

Tags: magento2, admin, multistore, store-view, multi-website

I have a website that has multiple sub-domains. The sub-domains are all connected to the same files but have been styled differently depending on the sub-domain. I would like each sub-domain to have their own store with their own products and customer. Each store would have to have a global admin account that would allow the admin to access all stores but then each sub-domain store would need to have their own admin account where this admin only has access to that one store and can only manage and upload products to that store. All the stores would have that same layout but styled differently (i.e. color and logos would be different)

I would like to know if this is possible and if so what store structure would I use and how can I achieve this?

I am using Magento community version 2.1.3

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion on how you could structure your site:

- 1 website per subdomain
- 1 custom theme/styling per website
- global admin user create for each store
- admin user for each store, with permissions only to that store
- products are scoped/loaded per store - easiest to just have the store admin manage products
- Out of the box; customers are unique to website so nothing to do here.

You'll likely need to tune your mysql.cnf (tmp_table setting) for indexers to run properly if you have a lot of websites.

How many websites are you planning on having?  How many sku's per website?

-Chuck

Comment: there will be a lot of sub-domains, hundreds actually. how would i create a user for each store, with permissions to only that store. I've tried to create another admin account but when you specify what is included in the role there is no option to pick which store view it would be for

Comment: It's a fairly common customization that's done for marketplace stores (on M1 - not sure of the details, haven't talked to anyone doing this on M2 yet); Most partners I talked to doing this on M1 further customized for performance as this isn't an out of the box use case (large # of websites/store views).  For example on M2 we've only tested with up to 25 websites / 50 store views (we're improving indexers in 2.2 to reduce hosting cost for that configuration - common for EU merchants, a website per country).  We take PRs - send them our way!